# Dynamic JavaScript If Statement

Tags: javascript, dynamic, logic, eval

In PHP I can do:

```
// $post = 10; $logic = >; $value = 100
$valid = eval("return ($post $logic $value) ? true : false;");
```

So the statement above would return false.

Can I do something similar in JavaScript? Thanks!

Darren.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Also, `$post $logic $value` returns a boolean, so there's no need for `? true : false`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, there's `eval` in javascript as well. for most uses it's not considered very good practice to use it, but i can't imagine it is in php either.

```
var post = 10, logic = '>', value = 100;
var valid = eval(post + logic + value);
```

Comment: Note: It's not safe.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to avoid `eval`, and since there are only 8 [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) in JavaScript, is fairly simple to write a small function, without using `eval` at all:

```
function compare(post, operator, value) {
  switch (operator) {
    case '>':   return post > value;
    case '<':   return post < value;
    case '>=':  return post >= value;
    case '<=':  return post <= value;
    case '==':  return post == value;
    case '!=':  return post != value;
    case '===': return post === value;
    case '!==': return post !== value;
  }
}
//...
compare(5, '<', 10); // true
compare(100, '>', 10); // true
compare('foo', '!=', 'bar'); // true
compare('5', '===', 5); // false
```

Comment: I love the endlessness of possibilities with coding. Cool shortener.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but you could've done the following:

```
var dynamicCompare = function(a, b, compare){
    //do lots of common stuff

    if (compare(a, b)){
        //do your thing
    } else {
        //do your other thing
    }
}

dynamicCompare(a, b, function(input1, input2){ return input1 < input2;}));
dynamicCompare(a, b, function(input1, input2){ return input1 > input2;}));
dynamicCompare(a, b, function(input1, input2){ return input1 === input2;}));
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript have an eval function too:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

```
eval("valid = ("+post+logic+value+");");
```